# What are the most popular .Net based CMS?

Tags: .net, content-management-system

I am looking for a flexible .Net based CMS that gives me most of the common CMS features as well as flexibility to build custom pages.

In CMS I am looking for following features.

- Support various content types
- Social network integration (Share on Twitter, Facebook, etc., Display Tweets from account )
- Ability promote content, feature content by editor
- Ability to control content displayed in certain parts of pages (e.g. displaying 10 hand picked items in a section on the homepage)
- Establish publishing workflows for any content
- Commenting, Voting
- Strong SEO support (Vanity URLs, Meta tags, etc.)
- Taxonomy support
- Tagging (keyword) content

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's the most popular, but [Umbraco](https://our.umbraco.org/) is a good option that should cover most of the features you've mentioned. It's also ridiculously easy to extend with custom functionality using its API.

[Asp.Net](http://www.asp.net/) has recently switched to using Umbraco. I guess that should count for something.

Answer (score 3):

You should choose **[Ektron](http://www.ektron.com/)** CMS,which will satisfy the requirements which you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check:

DotNetNuke

SiteFinity

Sharepoint? :D

Answer (score 1):

If you install [WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix) this will give you a list of some of the more popular ones.

I know this doesn't (exactly) answer your question but I think WebMatrix is a pretty good place to start and see which might best fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything in one CMS then you should use UMBRACO. It's one of the best CMS I have used. It's easy to use and Provide maximum features.
[Umbraco](http://umbraco.com/)